Is VC dimension of a hypothesis set H proportional to the number of effective hypotheses in H?
True or False. The VC dimension of a hypothesis set H is proportional to the number of effective hypotheses in H. Explain the reason if it is true.
This is what ChatGPT answers:

True. The VC (Vapnik-Chervonenkis) dimension of a hypothesis set
$$ is proportional to the number of effective hypotheses in
$$ because the VC dimension measures the capacity of
$H$ to shatter different arrangements of data points. A hypothesis set with a larger number of distinct, effective hypotheses will be capable of shattering more combinations of points, leading to a higher VC dimension.


If by "effective" hypotheses you mean distinct hypotheses, this sentence is false. VC dimension of a hypothesis set $H$ is simply the cardinality of a largest set of data points which can be shattered by $H$. Therefore $H$ containing a large number or even infinite number of distinct hypotheses could still have a low VC dimension, if $H$ cannot shatter many distinct arrangements of a small set of data points. For a simple example of $H$ which is the set of all 2D linear classifiers, its VC dimension is obviously 3 though $H$ has infinitely many distinct hypotheses as distinct lines in a 2D plane. You need to know $H$'s shattering capacity to decide its VC dimension in any proportional sense.
However, if by "effective" hypotheses you mean only those representative hypotheses from their own equivalence class of a hypothesis set $H$ which can shatter all arrangements of a set of data points, this sentence is (trivially) true, since per PAC theory, VC dimension $n$ is just defined as the finite "effective" size or complexity of an arbitrary hypothesis set $H$ to shatter a largest set of $n$ data points.
